# Best performance (or indications to judge) laptop cooling pad for pro use

Tags: laptop, cooling, performance

I run heavy data analysis on my 2014 MacBook Pro which just this year has started to show hardware problems exactly during long-duration computational tasks.

I decided to take a laptop cooling pad both to improve computing speed and protect the hardware.
I searched extensively on the web to get an idea of the best cooler on the market, but all I could find were many qualitative comparisons of products without objective quantitative assessments on performance (often they compares shapes, light effects and other things I'm not interested in).

Is there a clear winner(s) in term of cooling capabilities or at least some indication on what to compare (fan speed, number of fans, fans dispositions)? Even better if optimized for MacBook Pros, i.e. back-positioned exhaust vents, thermal concentration on the back.

I'd like to have objective/scientific indications in this regard. Price is not an issue (I didn't see any product above 100$ anyway)